# Compton no longer makes terminal windows transparent

Tags: i3-wm, compton

I had compton installed and added to my i3 config file, and it was working great until today it won't make the windows transparent on startup. When I tried killing the process (I have it setup as exec_always in my config file) and restarting it, I got this message on startup:

```
zach@sevastopol:~$ compton
[ 04/28/2020 11:06:33.739 x_fence_sync ERROR ] Failed to trigger the fence.
[ 04/28/2020 11:06:33.739 paint_all ERROR ] x_fence_sync failed, xrender-sync-fence will be disabled from now on.
```

And then it just sits there with a blinking cursor, doing nothing. Does anyone know what to do? I searched for this error message but there is nothing except for one post on Arch forums and it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Can You update Your post with compton config file? What gpu are You using? What drivers? Instead of using `xrender` You can try `glx` or vice versa. But my guess would be that maybe Your drivers are not being properly installed. Please attach output of `sudo lshw -c display`